# jquery convert JSON properties to string

Tags: jquery

I have the JSON format in the following way,

```
{  
   "id":"343",
   "css":{  
      "header":{  
         "background-color":"red",
         "color":"#FFF",
         "font-size":"12px"
      },
      "footer":{  
         "background-color":"blue",
         "color":"#000",
         "font-size":"11px"
      }
   }
}
```

I need to convert the JSON in the following way (i.e key and value pairs)

```
    css : 'header{"background-color":"red"; "color":"#FFF"; "font-size":"12px";} footer{ "background-color":"blue"; "color":"#000";"font-size":"11px";'}
```

Using jQuery how to convert the JSON in the above format. Is is possible to send like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate all the properties of the `css` property and iterate each of the sub properties

```
var style= '';
for(var selector in data.css){
    style += selector +'{';
    for(var prop in data.css[selector]){
        style += prop + ':' + data.css[selector][prop] +';';
    }
    style += '}';    
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/322ozk33/)**</kbd>